# Using subpackages with go mod locally

Tags: go, dependency-management, go-modules

I have a go package located on my filesystem (not in the `$GOPATH`), called `bitbucket.org/me/awesome`.

```
~/awesome> tree
.
├── main.go
├── go.mod
├── go.sum
├── subpackageA
│   └── main.go
```

My `go.mod` looks like:

```
module bitbucket.org/me/awesome

require (
       ... # lots of external dependencies
)

replace bitbucket.org/me/awesome => ./
```

In `main.go` in my top-level directory, I call a subpackage like follows:

```
import "bitbucket.org/me/awesome/subpackageA"
```

which all seems pretty normal. `go get` works. However, when I clone this entire repository somewhere else (say in a Docker image) and run `go get` for the first time, I get errors like:

`package bitbucket.org/me/awesome/subpackageA: https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/me/awesome?fields=scm: 403 Forbidden`,

which means it's not using the local filesystem version of the packages, even though I told it to with the [`replace` directive](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules#when-should-i-use-the-replace-directive) in the `go.mod` file.

What am I doing wrong? How do I ensure that subpackages are used from the filesystem instead of attempting to be fetched from the internet?

Comment: Yoe seem to have a replace directive for bitbucket.org/me/awesome only but the problem is with bitbucket.org/me/awesome/subpackageA. Do not think of a package in a folder as a subpackage: It is not. It is a standalone package _without_ _any_ relation to what is in the "parent" folder.

Comment: @Volker thanks, that was the tip that fixed this problem for me (adding other `replace` lines for subpackages). Do you want to add your comment as an answer?

Comment: I don't quite understand this problem statement. It seems all the packages in question here are all in the same `bitbucket.org/me/awesome` module, and packages within the same module should find each other automatically without needing a `replace` directive.

Comment: (Also, `replace` directives only operate on _modules_ as the left-side and right-side arguments, and not on subpackages or packages, unless a package is in the root of the module, in which case the package path and module path are the same, but even then the `replace` directive is really operating at the module level).

Comment: There is a bit more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57314494/11210494) on how packages find each other within the same module, and how that relates overall module structure.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Go has no (real) notion of "subpackage". All packages are basically treated equal. This means that a `replace bitbucket.org/me/awesome` does not influence package `bitbucket.org/me/awesome/subpackageA` as these are two individual, unrelated packages. The folder layout does not introduce a relation of subpackageA to awsome, or the other way around *).

So you need to add an individual replace directive for subpackageA

```
replace bitbucket.org/me/awesome/subpackageA => ./subpackageA
```

*) Nitpicking for absolute correctness: Folder layout does have influence for folders named `internal` (cannot be imported from other projects), for folders named `vendor` (which may contain vendored packages) and searching for a `go.mod` file stops at the repo root.

Comment: Where should I put this code:
`replace bitbucket.org/me/awesome/subpackageA => ./subpackageA`
Or is it just a step? Pls be clear.

Comment: @RajeshPaul in go.mod. Please read the Tutorials in go.dev/doc carefully (once more).

Answer (score 3):

For another approach, you can have `go.mod` like this:

```
module awesome
```

Then call subpackage like this:

```
import "awesome/subpackageA"
```

https://golang.org/doc/code.html